# Google Collections sources don't compile

Tags: java, guava

I just downloaded the Google Collections sources and imported them into a new Eclipse project with JDK 1.6.

They don't compile for a couple of reasons:

- javax.annotation.Nullable can not be found

  javax.annotation.ParametersAreNonnullByDefault can not be found

  Cannot reduce the visibility of the inherited method #createCollection() from AbstractMultimap

  + 11 similar ones

  Name clash: The method forcePut(K, V) of type AbstractBiMap has the same erasure as forcePut(Object, Object) of type BiMap but does not override it

  + 2 similar ones

What am I missing?

I also wonder if unit tests for these collections are available to the public.

Comment: Instead of using the download for the sources I should have got them with SVN straight away. SVN location is here: http://google-collections.googlecode.com/svn/

The jsr305.jar is included.

And yes, very nice JUnit tests are available too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like you're missing [JSR-305](http://code.google.com/p/jsr-305/) as dependency. Try adding it to the classpath.

Comment: Exactly, the missing jsr305.jar was the issue.